# how to populate a listview with only a part of an arraylist

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, arraylist

I dont know if this is possible but i want to ask, how can i populate a listview using only a portion of an arraylist. The content of my arraylist is from mySQL database(Im using volley). It is a list of items with category and item_name. What i want to do is whenever a button(category name) is pressed the item_names associated with that category will be displayed in the arrayList. Sorry for my bad english.

Here is my Codes: this displays all the item in my listView.

```
import ...

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.Listener<String> {

    final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public ListView itemList;
    public ArrayList<myItem> itemList;
    public myItemAdapter adapter;

    Button Fruit, Meat, Dairy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        String category = "http://10.0.2.2/myPHP/item.php";

        StringRequest stringRequestCategory = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, category, this, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequestCategory);

    Fruit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Fruit);
    Fruit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //display the items with the category FRUIT

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response);

        itemList = new JsonConverter<myItem>().toArrayList(response, myItem.class);

        adapter = new myCategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), itemList);
        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

PHP codes:

```
<?php
include_once ("init.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_item ORDER BY itemID ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to filter your list before sending it to your adapter.

Say you'll want to only display the category fruit.

```
Fruit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayList<myItem> filteredItems = new ArrayList<myItem>();
            for (myItem item : itemList) {
                // Not sure how your myItem class looks like but check category here.
                if ("fruit".equals(item.getCategory())) {
                    filteredItems.add(item);
                }
            }
            adapter.updateContent(filteredItems);
        }
    });
```

Add this method to your adapter class in order to update the displayed items in your ListView.

```
public void updateContent(List<myItem> items) {
    currentItems.clear();
    currentItems.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: where will i get the currentItems?

Comment: this method clears all the data in my ArrayList<myItem>. except the ones that meets the condition. but when i switch to a new category there is no more item to display.